# iOS SlideUp menu for phone numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Is there an solution on iOS where I could create an phone number picker menu like this? Does Apple support this view automatically or should I implement this alone?

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to get response of which number selected fro call from this native actionsheet UI?

Answer (score 0):

This is called UIAlertController's ActionSheet style in iOS. You can show ActionSheet with below code:

```
        let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Phone", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Add your code here when Phone action Tapped
    }
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Mobile", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Add your code here when Mobile action Tapped
    }
    let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "iPhone", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Add your code here when iPhone action Tapped

    }
    let action4 = UIAlertAction(title: "Private", style: .default) { (action) in
        // Add your code here when Private action Tapped

    }
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { (action) in
        // Add your code here when Cancel action Tapped

    }

    // To set image in ActionButton
    action1.setValue(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "check").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")

    // Add Actions to AlertController
    actionSheet.addAction(action1)
    actionSheet.addAction(action2)
    actionSheet.addAction(action3)
    actionSheet.addAction(action4)
    actionSheet.addAction(cancel)

    // Present UIAlertController
    present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

[image]

Comment: Thats right, but I would like to have also 2 lines in action sheet

Comment: Is there also an solution to set 2 lines? in my example you should see and Title and subtitle

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own menu as per your requirement using `UIActionSheet`

```
let actionSheet = UIActionSheet(title: "Choose Option", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel", destructiveButtonTitle: nil, otherButtonTitles: "Save", "Delete")
actionSheet.showInView(self.view)
```